# Живой поиск jquery

Tags: jquery, поиск

Тут уже были такие вопросы, но касались они немного другого.
Проблема вот в чем, событие поиска навешано на keyup и когда пользователь набирает слово, то одновременно на сервер идут несколько запросов, каждый из которых возвращает результат, который в интерфейсе затирает предыдущий. Это плохо для восприятия пользователем и сильно грузит БД.
Подскажите варианты, как можно это разрулить. Можно событие не на keyup прикрутить, а на blur, но пользователи уже привыкли к выводу результат при вводе тескта, так что пока пытаюсь что-то доработать с keyup.

Comment: много там результатов?

Comment: Можно делать как-то так: если после ввода буквы прошла секунда и дальше ввод не происходил, тогда делать запрос.
С jquery плохо знаком, так что нужно мне показать куда смотреть...

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/74713/

Answer (score 1):

Доля истины во временной задержке есть, но ориентирована она должна быть на людей, которые достаточно быстро набирают текст. Остается определиться со временем этой задержки. На мой взгляд, это может быть 250-400мс. Ну, а реализовать достаточно просто - смотрите [этот примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/SuLMs/)

P.S. Хм... Вот что бывает, когда начинаешь велосипедить до того, как пересмотришь мануалы )) Решение временной задержки, есть в самом виджете Autocomplete - [delay](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay):

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ delay: 500 });
```

Comment: Я же говорю, autocomplete тут не используется, это отдельная библиотека

Comment: @nMike, тогда пример в ответе был не лишним.

Comment: Да все уже, методом проб и ошибок какого-то результата удалось достичь.

Answer (score 0):

Это так и делается, событие на key, и замена вывода результата, еще решения не видел, так и все плагины работают(выше написали).
Просто оптимизировать запрос в базу, индексировать ее, ввести лимит на выдачу результатов, так же можно сделать что будет искать только по наличии четного количества букв (2/4/6 и т.п.). 
Так же можно запоминать (LocalStorage к примеру) результат поиска, это позволит избежать лишней нагрузки.

Comment: Ну нет. Я вижу рабочий пример, где запрос идет именно после определенного временного промежутка после ввода последнего символа, если введен следующий символ, то запрос на предыдущий не отправляется. Это как раз с jQuery AutoComplete делалось, только он там еще под себя переделан и используется на другом сайта. В этой задаче его не хотят использовать.

Пытаюсь че-нибудь сообразить с setTimeout, но пока не работает

Comment: Или скажем если вызван запрос, а предыдущий ответ еще не пришел, то убить все предыдущие запросы и сделать новый.

Comment: C временной задержкой это не совсем живой поиск. А так не чего сложного нет, в отправке защиты по времени. И не убьете Вы запросы которые уже отправлены) если у Вас так нагибается машина что надо убивать запросы, живой поиск не Ваше решение.

Comment: Задержку сделал, остался вопрос с запросами, неплохо бы обрабатывать результат только последнего запроса, а предыдущие нет. В php при этом не лазить.

Comment: Результат тоже вроде разрулил